How to add new column to existing abp table __core_EntityPropertyChange
I am using abp(aspnet boilerplate) framework. There is framework build table __core_EntityPropertyChange for auditing purpose.
Since this is framework build table so I am unable to add new column to this table using EF.
I created a custom class and try extending class EntityPropertyChange. I added this custom class to DbContext class, so that when I am running the add-migration then it should add new column to the framework build table but it is not happening.
public class Customclass : EntityPropertyChange 
{
    public string CustomColumn { get; set; }
}

Can someone please let me know how to add new column to this table using Entity Framework?
And also how data can be inserted to this column in this __core_EntityPropertyChange table.
Thanks in advance

I got answer to add new column to this table. Can someone please help to add data to this column. Where I need to inject so that data can be added same like other existing column
